# clojure nthrest and nthnext argument order

Tags: clojure, arguments

The [`nthrest`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/nthrest) function is called like : `(nthrest coll n)`.

The [`nthnext`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/nthnext) function is called like : `(nthnext coll n)`.

I thought that the rule was that `coll` was the last argument (as in `map`, `reduce`, `filter`...). At least that's how I think about it, especially when using the [`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) macro.

So, why does `nthrest` fo things differently, especially given that it was introduced in version [1.3](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3043) ?

Also see (from clojuredocs) :

```
(nthrest (range 10) 5)   ;;=> (5 6 7 8 9)
(drop    5 (range 10))   ;;=> (5 6 7 8 9)
```

Is it because it looks closer to `rest` in this case ? And if yes, what would it mean that there is another, stronger "rule" superseding the one I mentioned above that I am unaware of ?

Comment: `nthrest`and `nthnext` follow `nth` in argument order `[coll n]`. `nth` imitates `get`, which works only for indexed collections.

Comment: @Thumbnail right. I guess I should edit my question, it is about `nth` and `get` versus `map`, `reduce`, `filter` then. Wouldn't they compose more easily if there was a convention ?

Comment: I guess it's because the `get` itself is more or less optional, so putting the index last preserves the shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think it makes sense now.  Yes it would be nice for threading if the collection was always in the same position, but threading isn't the only concern.

For example, the [`partial`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial) function is only capable of partially-filling arguments at the start of a function's parameter list, and doesn't have a partial-last that works the other way round. I've rarely made a function using [`partial`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial) which takes a collection and returns a fixed key's value from it, but I've often made one which takes a key and returns its value from a fixed collection.

Functions such as [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) or [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) make sense if you think in terms of transducers.  Creating a transducer by omitting the collection is a conceptually sensible thing to do - it's nice not to couple my mapping call with the collection I want to run it on.  I like to think of the single-arity version of [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/search?q=map) (and similar transducer-returning versions of other collection functions) as being the default, with a convenience arity that allows me to specify the collection for those situations where I don't want to reuse my transducer elsewhere.  In this context, it makes sense to have the collection last.

Essentially, it's a question of taste - do you prefer a bias towards threading (which is very nice), higher-order functions or something else?  I'd recommend using [`as->`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/as-%3E) and not worrying too much about it!